# Transposing data to be aligned in two columns

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

Hoping for assistance with the following dataset. I have a large dataset that I need to get the location and part numbers to the right of the location transposed into two columns with the location being duplicated per part number.

The initial data looks like this:

```
Location    PartNumber  PartNumber  PartNumber  PartNumber  PartNumber  PartNumber  PartNumber
Location1   PartA0001   PartA0002   PartA0003   PartA0004   PartA0005   PartA0006   PartA0007
Location2   PartB0001   PartB0002   PartB0003   PartB0004   PartB0005   PartB0006   PartB0007
Location3   PartC0001   PartC0002   PartC0003   PartC0004   PartC0005   PartC0006   PartC0007
```

And I then need it to transpose like this:

```
Location    PartNumber
Location1   PartA0001
Location1   PartA0002
Location1   PartA0003
Location1   PartA0004
Location1   PartA0005
Location1   PartA0006
Location1   PartA0007
Location2   PartB0001
Location2   PartB0002
Location2   PartB0003
Location2   PartB0004
Location2   PartB0005
Location2   PartB0006
Location2   PartB0007
Location3   PartC0001
Location3   PartC0002
Location3   PartC0003
Location3   PartC0004
Location3   PartC0005
Location3   PartC0006
Location3   PartC0007
```

Hope this makes sense and appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Search for `unpivot`. Plenty of examples using a variety of techniques.  Probably the simplest would be with Power Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **A1** through **H4**, in **A7** enter:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/7,0))
```

and copy downwards.  In **B7** enter:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$H$4,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/7,0),MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,7)+1)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

*(Any 2-D table can be mapped into a single column or single row)*